# Edit/Update many to many relation ASP.NET Core MVC and Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, many-to-many

I am using EF Core in an ASP.NET Core MVC web app.

I have a many to many relations between a Store and a Dish (a Dish has List of Store and a store has List of Dish)

I have these tables in the database: `Store, Dish, DishStore`

It is an online restaurant. I want to let the user to change the stores when editing a Dish.

Here is and example of how i implemented a create a of a Dish, everything works just fine here when creating a Dish - the DishStore table is updated perfectly.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public IActionResult Create()
{
        ViewData["Store"] = new MultiSelectList(_context.Store, nameof(Store.Id), nameof(Store.City));
        ViewData["FoodGroupId"] = new SelectList(_context.FoodGroup, nameof(FoodGroup.Id), nameof(FoodGroup.Name));
        return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,FoodGroupId,Description,Price,ImageFile")] Dish dish, int[] Store)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var q = _context.Dish.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == dish.Name);
            if (q == null)
            {
                dish.Store = new List<Store>();
                dish.Store.AddRange(_context.Store.Where(x => Store.Contains(x.Id)));

                if (dish.Store.Count == 0)
                {
                    ViewData["Error"] = "You have to choose at least one store.";
                    return View(dish);
                }

                _context.Add(dish);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["Error"] = "Unable to comply; cannot create the Dish.";
            }
        }

        ViewData["FoodGroupId"] = new SelectList(_context.FoodGroup, nameof(FoodGroup.Id), nameof(FoodGroup.Name), dish.FoodGroupId);
        return View(dish);
}
```

The problem starts when I try to edit a Dish.

how could I give the user an option to update/remove existing stores?how could I change the rows in the DishStore table without delete the existing Stores from Store table.

I tried few options without success.

Edit Dish code:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var dish = await _context.Dish.FindAsync(id);

        if (dish == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        ViewData["Store"] = new SelectList(_context.Store, nameof(Store.Id), nameof(Store.City));
        ViewData["FoodGroupId"] = new SelectList(_context.FoodGroup, nameof(FoodGroup.Id), nameof(FoodGroup.Name), dish.FoodGroupId);

        return View(dish);
}

// POST: Dishes/Edit/5
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Name,FoodGroupId,Description,Price,ImageFile")] Dish dish, int[] Store)
{
        if (id != dish.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                    //Edit stores here
                    _context.Update(dish);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!DishExists(dish.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        ViewData["FoodGroupId"] = new SelectList(_context.FoodGroup, nameof(FoodGroup.Id), nameof(FoodGroup.Name), dish.FoodGroupId);
        return View(dish);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: How did you define/map the model in EF?

Comment: What did you try and what is the error?

Comment: Hi, i found the solution using : _context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Detached;

Comment: @user91489 Hi, could you pls post your answer below to end this case sir? Thanks in advance : )